# pickling QWidgets and classes inheriting QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, pickle

I have been trying to save the widgets in my QTabWidget to a file, that I can later load and add the saved widgets as tabs in the current window.

My approach was trying to use pickle, however pickle.dump returns a type error.

Is it possible to save QWidgets?

I have defined a custom canvas class inheriting QWidget that contains the QGraphicsScene and view as follow.

```py
class canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(canvas, self).__init__(parent)

        self.painter = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 794, 1123)
        self.resize(794, 1123)
        self.painter.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.painter)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

which is then added to the QTabWidget.

All I want is to save a list of objects of my canvas class to a file

Here is a minimum reproducible example.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tabs = []
    tabs.append(canvas())
    tabs.append(canvas())
    tabs.append(canvas())
    pickle.dump(tabs, open('test','w'))
```

Comment: Widgets cannot be "saved" or pickled. You'll have to find your own way of serializing the data you want to store and then unserialize it back, according to your needs.

Comment: using getstate and setstate? Since I need to also save and restore all items added to the GraphicsScene.... Wouldnt that become complicated very quick? Since the items in QGraphicsScene may not just be the standard classes?

Comment: Exactly because you're probably using non standard classes, you'll need to implement the serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked for me, do note that all items that are added to the painter need to be subclassed so as to add the getstate and setstate property. 
I havent tested it for the items inside the QGraphicsScene however

```py
def __getstate__(self) -> dict:
    return {
        "_classname_": self.__class__.__name__,
        "ObjectName": self.objectName(),
        "items": [i.__getState__() for i in self.painter.items()]
    }
def __setstate__(self, dict):
    self.__init__()
    self.setObjectName(dict['ObjectName'])
    for item in dict['items']:
        graphic =  getattr(graphics, dict['_classame_'])
        graphic.__setstate__(item)
        self.painter.addItem(graphic)
```